# Wrap three repeating div groups into one using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have another problem here. I have few repeating groups of divs. There is 3 divs with different classes in one group.

What I need to do is wrap the into one 'container'. When I'm using wrapAll it wraps all into one div.

And this is my html:

```
<div class="bb_box_tl"></div>
<div class="bb_box_l"></div>
<div class="bb_box_lb"></div>

<div class="bb_box_tl"></div>
<div class="bb_box_l"></div>
<div class="bb_box_lb"></div>

<div class="bb_box_tl"></div>
<div class="bb_box_l"></div>
<div class="bb_box_lb"></div>
```

This is all in one body.

As I result i would like to have them look like this:

```
<div class="box-cont">
    <div class="bb_box_tl"></div>
    <div class="bb_box_l"></div>
    <div class="bb_box_lb"></div>
</div>

<div class="box-cont">
    <div class="bb_box_tl"></div>
    <div class="bb_box_l"></div>
    <div class="bb_box_lb"></div>
</div>

<div class="box-cont">
    <div class="bb_box_tl"></div>
    <div class="bb_box_l"></div>
    <div class="bb_box_lb"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote just the plugin for this a while ago

```
(function($){

   $.fn.wrapChildren = function(options) {

    var options = $.extend({
                              childElem : undefined,
                              sets : 1,
                              wrapper : 'div'
                            }, options || {});
    if (options.childElem === undefined) return this;

 return this.each(function() {
  var elems = $(this).children(options.childElem);
  var arr = [];

  elems.each(function(i,value) {
    arr.push(value);
    if (((i + 1) % options.sets === 0) || (i === elems.length -1))
   {
     var set = $(arr);
     arr = [];
     set.wrapAll($("<" + options.wrapper + ">"));
   }
  });
    });

  }

})(jQuery);
```

You pass in an options object defining

- childElem - the filter selector of the immediate children to wrap
- sets - how you want to group the child elements. For example, sets of 3 in your case. Default is 1
- wrapper - the element to wrap the child elements in. default is `<div>`

Use like so on your data. You need to define a parent element for the divs

```
$(function() {   
  $('body').wrapChildren({ 
             childElem : 'div.bb_box_tl, div.bb_box_l, div.bb_box_lb' , 
             sets: 3, 
             wrapper: 'div class="box-cont"'
  });   
});
```

Here's a [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/idize) with some data.

**UPDATE:**

[**I wrote a blog post with a slightly modified and improved version of this**](http://forloop.co.uk/blog/wrap-child-elements-in-groups-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your div's are all children of an element with id container (else change jquery selector) and the appear strictly in this order

```
while ($("#container > div[class^='bb_box_']").size() >= 3)
  $("#container > div[class^='bb_box_']:lt(3)").wrapAll("<div class='box-cont'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted but I couldn't think of an easier way. It works though:

```
$("div.bb_box_tl").wrap("<div class='box-cont'></div>");
$("div.box-cont").each(function() {
  $(this).append($(this).next());
  $(this).append($(this).next());
});
```

Comment: You definitely beat me to it, but I'm not sure that you can add jQuery elements - I thought add only takes a selector expression or a DOM element.

Comment: **.bb_box_t1** needs to be **.bb_box_tl**, but im not sure this will work

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert, but this might work:

```
$(".bb_box_tl").before('<div class="box-cont">');
$(".bb_box_lb").after('</div>');
```

Comment: Well it definitely should. Probably replace `.bb_box_tl` with `div.bb_box_tl` etc.

Comment: This doesn't work because when you add the `<div>` before, the DOM sees no closing tag, so it automatically adds it immediately after the `<div>` that was just added.