# jQuery wrap sets of elements in div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hello I would like to use jQuery to wrap sets of elements in a div

HTML:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
<li>Feature</li>
<li>Feature</li>
</ul>

<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
<li>Feature</li>
<li>Feature</li>
</ul>

<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
<li>Feature</li>
<li>Feature</li>
</ul>
```

Desired Result:

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>Title</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>Feature</li>
    <li>Feature</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="box">
    <h3>Title</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>Feature</li>
    <li>Feature</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="box">
    <h3>Title</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>Feature</li>
    <li>Feature</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

My question is similar to the following but I was unable to get the solution suggested by Russ Cam to work.

[Wrap three repeating div groups into one using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708429/wrap-three-repeating-div-groups-into-one-using-jquery)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('h3').each(function(){
  $(this).add( $(this).next() ).wrapAll('<div class="box"></div>');
 })
})
```