# Is there any equivalent of ".nextUntil" (Jquery) in Html Agility pack (asp.net)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to do something similar to this in asp.net

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6936916/4359164

Does anyone know if there is any equivalent to ".nextuntil" in Html Agility pack?

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAgilityPack can be used with LINQ so you have ability to do all that stuff.
For eg:

```
document.DocumentNode.Descendants().TakeWhile(n => n.Name.Equals("h5")) // Or SkipWhile
```

It depends on your real need.