# wrap tr in tbody in a group of certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using Javascript/Jquery, how do we wrap `<tr></tr>` into `<tbody></tbody>` in a group of a certain number.

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

I like to chance it to:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'd write some code. What have you tried?

Comment: i found .wrap() but didn't know how to group the <tr></tr>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap three repeating div groups into one using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708429/wrap-three-repeating-div-groups-into-one-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple usign [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/):

```
var trs = $("table tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i += 2) {
  trs.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<tbody/>");
}
```